# jQuery toggle method issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle

When using `jquery-ui-1.8.15.custom.min` `toggle` method, the element next to the target element is always hidden.

Here is the test page: http://jsfiddle.net/dassio/CLrMx/9

I want the `div` with class name `suggestion` to toggle between hidden and show when you click the button, but why the red line is always missing?

Comment: you should post a jsfiddle.net with the relevant part of code so that we could help

Comment: It will not fix your bug, but to begin, you have to rewrite your HTML code : `<div>` elements ar not allowed in `<ul>` if it are not in a `<li>`, `<link>` are not closed and missing `type='text/javascript'`  in `<scrip>` tag. Wrong HTML code can make unpredictable javascript behavior

Comment: thanks now i get a jsfiddle.net page:http://jsfiddle.net/dassio/CLrMx/9/   and i put the p inside the li element, is that validate?

Answer (score 1):

This should do the job:
http://jsfiddle.net/CLrMx/15/

Your script was accidentally hiding your text. Cleaned it up a bit so it olny does the necessary.

Comment: thanks any way . i found the problem: it is because i add the classname `name` to the parent `div`, and when the event bubble up the 'toggle' method is called. i am not allowed to post my answer right now, later i will get more detail description. thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem:

```
<div id="config" class='name ui-widget-content ui-corner-all'> 
    <button id="details">show details</button> 
</div>
```

I add the `name` class name to the parent `div` around the button, and when the event bubble up to the parent `div`, the following code:

```
$(".name" ).click(function() {
    var clicked = $(this);
    var suggestion = clicked.next();
    suggestion.toggle("fold",200);
    return false;
});
```

was called and toggle off the `<h3>` element which is the next element of the parent `div`.